# How to get click event of whole list item which contains grid view?

Tags: java, android

I have created a listview where it contains a textview and a grid view. Grid view item contains textview. It looks like the following:

```
Listview
---------------------------
Item 1
[grid item 1] [grid item 2]
---------------------------
Item 2
[grid item 1] [grid item 2]
[grid item 3] [grid item 4]
---------------------------
```

I have disabled the click event of grid view item by gridView.setEnabled(false); I wanted the whole list item to be clicked using onClickListener(). I can get the click event from partial area of list item. However, I am unable to get the click event from grid view area.

I have gone through several threads but unable to solve the stated issue.

I have tried:

1. Using `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` in topmost viewgroup of gridview item.
2. Using `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` in viewgroup containing gridview.
3. Using android:focusable="true" android:focusableInTouchMode="true" in viewgroup containing gridview.

I also tried other approaches from the various threads but could not solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to detect clicks on View objects you probably need to set `android:clickable="true"`in your XML.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:clickable

Comment: Gridview steals the focus of click event from the parent listview. It doesn't work by making the gridview item clickable to true.

Answer (score 0):

Solution: If one of the children has the focusable or clickable attribute to true then the parent won't be able to get focus or click event of that child's area.

I solved the issue by applying following method to gridview:

```
    gridView.setEnabled(false);
    gridView.setClickable(false);
    gridView.setFocusable(false);
```